# jetty set resource base within an external java lib (a.k.a jar file) while in Android

Tags: java, android, jetty

I had success deploying jetty 7 embedded server on Android the problem is i cannot set it to access folder within my *jar* file *(jar file runs perfectly on PC and has self contained dependencies, which is added on android as an external lib)*. i wish to set this folder as a **resourceBase** for my embedded web app

here is the full code

```
            System.out.println(" server init attempt on port:"+curPort);
            ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
            Server server = new Server(curPort);
            server.setHandler(context);
            context.setContextPath("/");         
            System.out.println(" servlet main initing");
            DSSServer servlet = new DSSServer();
            context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), "/DSS");
            ResourceHandler res = new ResourceHandler();
            System.out.println(" getting resBase:");
            //[code above works fine]

            //[!ATTENTION HERE!]
            String resDir = "/dss_core/HTML5/webapp";
            //This runs on PC fine but creates a null pointer exception in Android
            String resurl = DSSServer.class.getResource(resDir).toExternalForm();
            //Here is another non-working varient
            //String resurl = servlet.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resDir).toExternalForm();

            //[code below works fine]
            res.setResourceBase(resurl);
            res.setDirectoriesListed(true);
            context.setHandler(res);
            System.out.println(" servlet main inited");
```

this is the code block that makes the null pointer exception

```
            String resDir = "/dss_core/HTML5/webapp";
            //This runs on PC fine but creates a null pointer exception in Android
            String resurl = DSSServer.class.getResource(resDir).toExternalForm();
            //Here is another non-working variant
            //String resurl = servlet.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resDir).toExternalForm();
```

what is the correct way to access a external java library resource folder in Android, i know Android has it's own resource management system, but i cannot put native Android code in my external java lib as it is a jar file specifically for PC.

an alternative method i may do is extract my resource base to a local folder, but i'd rather not do that as it leaves tons of temporary files

BTW Android has no problem accessing one file at a time from inside my java lib

```
            //Accessing individual files work on Android 
            InputStream input = DatabaseManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/h2db.mv.db");
```

Comment: Did you `dex`-ify your external java lib before attempting to use it on Android? (or is it `art`-ify now?)

Comment: yup, only jetty7 can be dexed, also there has been success stories doing the same in IOS (roboVM), jetty 8 and 9 cannot be dexed, so i am stuck with jetty7

Comment: looks like i'll be answering my own question, i'll update this later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears such is not possible, i ended up extracting the files somewhere in Android (like /mnt/sdcard/.myApp/temp) and manually copying each and every single file there

```
String resDir = "/dss_core/HTML5/webapp";
String resurl = dss_core.util.DRYcode.platformIsAndroid()?"file:/mnt/sdcard/protected/"+servletName:
                DRYcodeWeb.class.getResource(resDir).toString();
if (dss_core.util.DRYcode.platformIsAndroid())
    for (String str:resourceList)
        DRYcode.copy_("/dss_core/HTML5/webapp/"+str,"/mnt/sdcard/protected/"+servletName+"/"+str);
```